# Explode string that contains delimiter repeated successively

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm looking how I can explode a string that where the delimiter is repeated successively but I didn't find the solution.

The string is: `$text = "43##567#####152990#572##017";` and I want to get the numbers in an `array()`.

I tried with `explode()` and putting the `+` as delimiter but it returns empty positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$res = preg_split('/\#+/', '43##567#####152990#572##017');
print_r($res);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 43
    [1] => 567
    [2] => 152990
    [3] => 572
    [4] => 017
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $text = "43##567#####152990#572##017";
    $data = array_filter(explode('#',$text));
    print_r($data);
?>
```

**please note** that it will remove zeroes aswell...

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) like this:

```
$data = "43##567#####152990#572##017";
$split_data = preg_split("/#?#+/is", $data, -1, null);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($split_data);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the results would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 43
    [1] => 567
    [2] => 152990
    [3] => 572
    [4] => 017
)
```